# How to put <Route children={({match})} => ... > in Jsx fragment. React router dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

return (
<>

Some jsx..

```
            <Route
                path={modal.info ? `/fullInfo/${this.state.modal.id}`:`/preview/${this.state.modal.id}`}
                element={({match}) => {
                    return (
                        <ModalWindow
                            modalVisible={Boolean(match)}
                            onCloseWindow={this.onCloseWindow}
                            modalContent={modal}
                        />
                    )
                }}
            />
            
        </>
    )
```

If I do that I get an error like: Route tag must be wrapped by Routes tag. I did this feature in a old version of react-router-dom but when I try to do it in the new one there is err..

Comment: The `Routes` component effectively replaced the `Switch` component from v5, and it's required to wrap any `Route` components.

Answer (score 0):

In your App.js file, wrap the entire app with `<BrowserRouter>`

```
const AppWithRouter = () => <BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>
export default AppWithRouter
```

And then wrap all your routes in the new `<Routes>` tag (replaces switch):

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="..." element={...} />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Routes` component effectively replaced the `Switch` component from v5, and it's required to wrap any `Route` components. Additionally, the `Route` components no longer take `component`, and `render` and `children` prop functions, the routed components must use the `element` prop that takes a `ReactElement`, a.k.a. JSX.

Wrap the `Route` component in a `Routes` component and since all routes are always exactly matched, just render the `ModalWindow` with the `modalVisible` prop set to true.

```
return (
  <>
    ...Some jsx...
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path={modal.info
          ? `/fullInfo/${this.state.modal.id}`
          :`/preview/${this.state.modal.id}`
        }
        element={(
          <ModalWindow
            modalVisible
            onCloseWindow={this.onCloseWindow}
            modalContent={modal}
          />
        )}
      />
    </Routes>    
  </>
)
```